# Should I be using the OpenGeo Suite SDK or GeoEXT?

Tags: openlayers-2, geoext, boundless-suite, sdk, geoexplorer

Im new to the OpenGeo Suite, and was wondering if I should create my apps using the SDK [Link  Here](http://suite.opengeo.org/opengeo-docs/apps/index.html) Or I should use openlayers and GeoEXT [Link here](http://workshops.opengeo.org/openlayers-intro/)

I believe the SDK uses openlayers / geoext but makes the creation of map applications user friendly? I just need to know what to use each for in the terms of a new user

EDITS:

I want to create an app that displays layers, I have done that with the SDK pretty easy with GXP. However I also want to add graphs/charts to the maps, this is where I am unsure which route to go down. The user would click on a point and would be able to view a chart of that points change over time.

Comment: They serve different purposes, so to get a meaningful answer, you;ll need to explain what you are trying to do, in much more detail (you can do this - just click edit below your question), what the constraints and objectives are, and what you've already tried (and how that went).

Comment: @BradHards Extra info added

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few ways of accomplishing what you want. I will try to share some of the resources I have found useful. How you implement it obviously has a big influence on what you will use, e.g building the graph client side, requesting a graph from the back-end, will the graph be displayed on request or as part of the initial layout etc..

**Assuming that you created your project using the `gxp` template**

`geoext`, as you might have noticed extends `extjs`, so for manipulating geographic data use the `geoext` API, but for the rest I would suggest looking at the `extjs` API, the version that is rolled out with boundless is 3.4 (as far as I could determine), [here is the API](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/), another useful link is [their examples](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.4.0/examples/), here you will find chart examples that will hopefully do what you need.

**Assuming that you created your project using the `ol3view` or `ol3edit` template**

With this you simply need to hook up a library that can render the graph given a data set, there are allot of [JS graphing libraries](http://www.sitepoint.com/15-best-javascript-charting-libraries/), so it will boil down to whether the library provides the required functionality.

As [BradHards](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/8563/bradhards) said, a code snippet or more detail regarding what you have already tried might get you a more specific/detailed answer. Although I hope that these resources will get you started or at least give you a better idea of the practicality of what you are trying to do.