# OpenGeo Suite create map application GXP or GeoEXT

Tags: openlayers-2, geoext, boundless-suite, sdk

I have seen a similar question but it never got answered. I am looking to develop a GIS system using the OpenGeo Suite, luckily I'm going to a conference on it in a few weeks, however that's weeks away.

I need to work on my front end, and I am really confused over GXP and GeoEXT, what should I be using to create my map application? the OpenGeo website has tutorials for both...

The system will enable panning/zoom, layer tree, maybe graphs, edit/features (click and change fields), grideditor, legend. Do I go down the OpenLayers route with GeoEXT or use SDK GXP. I am confused because some of the OpenGeo videos by themselves, seem to make out GXP is the way forward but then many examples and documentation they have, uses OpenLayers/GeoEXT.

This was the question, he basically wanted the same as me [link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/66422/should-i-be-using-the-opengeo-suite-sdk-or-geoext)

Comment: Welcome to GIS Stack Exchange!  So that we can easily find the previous question you refer to could you include a link (which you can embed) to it, please?

Comment: @PolyGeo I attached the question I had seen before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok.

The GXP library is probably your best bet if you want simple and are using the OpenGeo Stack. The GXP library actually includes the GeoEXT library an basically just extends it to make the creation of Maps and the inclusion of the GXP plugins simpler.

The GXP library requires GeoEXT, EXT and the Openlayers libraries.

I hope that is helpful.